# How to create xcframework for obj c static library?

Tags: static-libraries, xcframework

I have a static library mostly written in objective c / c++ called libA. Now I want to use the headers in another static library called libB which is on swift.

Therefore, I had to expose the headers via Bridging-Header.h and create an empty swift file in libA in order to import the libA in libB's swift classes as import A.

Now I want to create binary framework (xcframework) for libA, for this purpose I have to enable Build Libraries for Distribution but I cannot do it because I am using Bridging-Header.h in libA

How should I proceed now?